# How to automatically give a different color to the lines in FacetGrid.map

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, relplot

Suppose we want to use `FacetGrid.map(sns.lineplot)` twice on the same FacetGrid. May I ask how can we automatically get a different color in the second `FacetGrid.map(sns.lineplot)`?

Below is a minimal example to demonstrate the situation:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips, height=6)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'size', 'tip', ci=None)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'size', 'total_bill', ci=None)
```

[image]

What I want is that the two lines are of different colors automatically. Thank you so much in advance!

PS: I know that I can alternatively use `sns.lineplot` twice instead of using `g.map`, but `sns.lineplot` doesn't allow me the flexibility to specify `col` and `row` parameters, and so I want to use `g.map` instead.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to melt the dataframe so `total_bill`/`tip` are observations of the same variable:

```
sns.relplot(
    data=tips.melt("size", ["total_bill", "tip"]),
    x="size", y="value", hue="variable",
    kind="line", ci=None,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the dataframe to ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data), and then use hue:

```py
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=tips.melt(id_vars='size', value_vars=['tip', 'total_bill']), hue='variable', height=6)
g.map(sns.lineplot, 'size', 'value', ci=None)
# g.add_legend()  # to add a figure-level legend
```

[image: sns.FacetPlot with two line plots]